# How to set boot disk size on a google cloud deployment vps

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm creating a simple vps from the google cloud deployment configuration that is like this:

```
resources:
  - name: cdh5-zookeeper-01
    type: compute.v1.instance
    properties:
      zone: us-central1-f
      machineType: zones/us-central1-f/machineTypes/n1-standard-1
      disks:
      - deviceName: boot
        type: PERSISTENT
        boot: true
        autoDelete: true
        initializeParams:
          sourceImage: projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-1404-trusty-v20161010
          diskSizeGb: 50
      networkInterfaces:
      - network: global/networks/default
        accessConfigs:
        - name: External NAT
          type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

This works except that the `diskSizeGb` does not match the value specified, did someone found out how to create a bootdisk with a different size?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this was just an issue with the gcloud deployment tools at the time. I managed to create custom size CoreOS boot disks with a very similar resource file using version:

```
$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 172.0.0
beta 2017.09.15
bq 2.0.26
core 2017.09.15
gcloud 
gsutil 4.27
```